# Get selected Image within onTouchListener

Tags: android, selection, ontouchlistener

I've got a Button in my testing activity which shows several images while being held down. Looks like circuit selection.

How could I give the onTouchListener or MotionEvent the information which image is selected while holding the Button and release over one of these?(in Action_UP for example)

Is there any opportunity to get a boolean for "that image is -istouched-", that would be the best for me!

Comment: Associate boolean value to your custom button, if button is not custom you can use setTag and getTag methods, otherwise you can have a boolean array to keep references

Comment: So do i have to set my images as an ImageButton?

Comment: You can extend ImageView or ImageButton to create your CustomButton with a custom boolean attribute to know if it has been touched or not.

Comment: thanks! i understand your idea but how can i check that? Well I touch and hold the button -> images appear (8) -> within the switch case witch I use for the MotionEvents i got the Event_UP -> ?

There must be the check witch button "wasHovered". I dont think that this is a "Click" then I do the MOTION_UP over there. 
onTouchListener{
declarations declarations....     
switch case      
MOTION DOWN   
 [...]      

MOTION UP   
ImagesDisappear   
"Witch_Image_is_hovered_while_MotionUP" <-?

Well this is my imagination...

Thanks for all